# How to add Social Like . sharing and contact button in android drawer navigation

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I want add social like and contact button on my drawer navigation footer .
like this image (http://postimg.org/image/3mcbdod21/)
 please help me .

Comment: Please read before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes am using android navigation drawer

I add footer in drawer navigation and its look like (http://postimg.org/image/chsryx1qx/)

here is my code
footer1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#7A7A7A"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center">



     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fb"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
             />
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:background="@drawable/twitter"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
             />
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/google"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:background="@drawable/google"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
footer.java

package com.hdwh.android.wallpaper;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Footer extends BaseActivity {

    ImageButton imgButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.footer1);

          addListenerOnButton();
        }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

          imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById
          (R.id.facebook);

          imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              String url = "http://www.facebook.com.";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
            }

          });
    }


          private void addListenerOnButton1() {

          imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById
          (R.id.twitter);

          imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              String url = "http://www.twitter.com.";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
            }
          });
          }
          private void addListenerOnButton2() {

          imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById
          (R.id.google);

          imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              String url = "http://plus.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
            }
          });
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layout and set it as layout align parent bottom in the xml file of drawer menu(are you using android navigation drawer?)